# Are there any CopyOnRead lists or other implementations in Java?

Tags: java, list, multithreading, collections, concurrency

Write operations more than read operations, what is the implementation?
I searched a lot, but nothing came up.
I need a list collection that supports concurrent programming.

My program:
Netty is used, and there is a list to store connections that are not logged in.
The user is added to the list when the connection is successful.
The user is deleted from the list after successful login.
Unlogged connections are cleared every 30 seconds.

So I need a list with more write operations than read operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying on read<sup>1</sup> would not be a concurrency optimization<sup>2</sup>.  Thus, there are no concurrent copy-on-read implementations of `List`.

A number of concurrent implementations of `Queue` or `Deque` exist, in both blocking and non-blocking forms.

However, if your application really requires a `List` (rather than a `Queue` or `Deque`), your best option is to use a mutex to synchronize ALL access and update operations on the list.  It is not highly concurrent, but *c'est la vie*!

Looking at your use-case, it seems to me that you actually need a concurrent set or map rather than a list.  Your comments confirm this.

---

<sup>1 - Copy-on-read is sometimes used to refer to the practice of returning a copy of an internal data structure via an API.  This is orthogonal to concurrency / thread-safety.

2 - As far as I am aware ...</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I'll try concurrent set or map.

Comment: In Java 17, Set<Channel> ALL_NOT_LOGGED_IN_CONNECTION = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()
Will this meet my needs?

Comment: Data is added to the collection every minute, but it is cleaned up every 30 seconds to close connections that are not logged in

Comment: Sounds right.  Give it a try.

Comment: @gdrfgdrf how does the cleanup code determine that a connection is worth closing (“not logged in”), in contrast to an ongoing login? According to your description in the question, a connection is added once established and “deleted from the list after successful login” which means during the login procedure, concurrent cleanup would close the connection.